# Creating a login page for users in react

Tags: reactjs

Im new to react but have some experience with php/wordpress, I have created a login form, its currently not got any user to login to, with wordpress you add a connection to a database and the users data is stored in a database (e.g mysql) and you can use logic to allow user to login, would you do the same with react.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";


export default class Login extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state ={email:"", password:""};
    }
    render()
    {
        return <div className="col-lg-9">
            <h4 className="m-1 p-2 border-bottom">Login</h4>
            <div className="form-group form-row">
                <label className="col-lg-4">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.email}
                onChange={(event)=>{this.setState({email:event.target.value}); console.log(this.state.email);}}/>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group form-row">
                <label className="col-lg-4" value={this.state.password} 
                onChange={(event)=>{this.setState({password:event.target.value}); console.log(this.state.password);}} >Password:</label>
                <input type="password" className="form-control"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.onLoginClick}>Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
    onLoginClick = () =>
    {
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### I will recommend you to use MongoDB [using mongoose library] here

Whereas if you want to use MySQL then Checkout : [MySQL with NodeJs](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp)

For MongoDB one You might need to create a backend server

For eg. with express.js you can create a RESTFul API to interact with Database

#### You Can Checkout some Online Courses for Express and MongoDB

##### Some Useful Links

- [express.js](https://expressjs.com/)
- [mongoose.js](https://mongoosejs.com/)

Comment: Yes thanks, that's what I was looking for, I will try the MongoDB method.

Answer (score 0):

The function onLoginClick function will send email and password to the server and will receive the return results, from which we will process if the results return true and false.

Comment: The function works when I click the login button, however there is no database where the user data is stored but as I am new to react the way I would do it is to establish a database connection and then the returned results will determine the out put, would that be the way to do it in react.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).